# Angular: Detect only FormControls that changed

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

To detect value changes in a FormGroup I use the following code:

```
this.settingsForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
  console.log(val);
});
```

The problem is that val represents the entire `FormGroup` value. What I'm interested is to find exactly what `FormControl`(s) changed.

I know you can do something like this

```
this.settingsForm.get('email').valueChanges.subscribe(val=>{});
```

but If I have 20 items in my form I don't what to create 20 subscriptions.

Comment: what about finding all dirty controls
`const keyValue = Object.entries(this.settingsForm.controls).filter(value => value[1].dirty);`

Comment: I think using filter we can check specific changed value. very nice idea thanks @Reza and Doua for your useful answer and question

Comment: @RezaRahmati not a bad approach. Just a note..if you have nested forms you need to implement this recursively